# How to initialize view without known frame?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm building view without `.xib` file, just using `loadView` method. But in the point, when loadView is called, the frame of view is yet unknown. So, I use it just to build view hierarchy without concrete frames. (Than I update view's layout when it's frame is known.)
The question is: should I use `[[UIView alloc] init]` or `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]` or may be something else, to initialize view without known frame?
Here is the code:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    // or 
    // UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    // or something else?        

    // ...

    self.view = containerView;
    [containerView release];
}
```

Comment: CGRectZero is quite good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`- (id)initWithFrame:` is the designated initializer for `UIView`, so you should use that, with a zero-sized rect.